# Override external less style element

Tags: html, css, less

I have an angularjs npm project which is using many external libraries to render various elements on the frontend.

Style is defined into external libraries .less or .css file.

My project is using many different .less files that will be merged together into a big .css at the end of the build process.

I cannot change or manipulate external libraries directly, wat I want to do is to extend and in some cases override external library elements, to use the same element names as they were coming from the extern lib but modified with my local change, as follows:

External Library .css

```
.squeezebox .sb-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.squeezebox .sb-item-head a {
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}

.squeezebox .sb-item .sb-item-body {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s height;
}

.squeezebox .sb-item .sb-item-body .inner {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

My local .less file:

```
&override(.squeezebox .sb-item .sb-item-body .inner) {
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}
```

Or:

```
&extend(.squeezebox .sb-item .sb-item-body .inner) {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Which is the best practice to obtain this?

Comment: This is not related to angularjs

Comment: The way you have it just plain `.squeezebox .sb-item .sb-item-body .inner {padding-top: 0px}` will do the trick (please don't use the freaking `!imp` where not deadly required). And yes it's just plain CSS not even Less.